# I cant import function module to react native error : "Unable to resolve module"

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

i make a react native app in expo and i try put my functions in another js file but i cant import the console show the error :

"Unable to resolve "../../funciones/funciones" from "pages/register.js""

but the directorio its correct...

in my functions file :

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import { Alert }  from 'react-native';

class funciones {
    register (name, username, mail, password) {
        axios.post('/signup', {
            name: name,
            username: username,
            mail: mail,
            password: password
        }) .then(response => {
            return true
        }) .catch(error => {
            Alert.alert(error)
        })
    }
}

export default new funciones()
```

in my "register" file import:

```js
import funciones from '../../funciones/funciones'
```

Thanks 4 the help

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo between the class name and exported function name. You have `funiones` on class name but `funciones` on export default

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to go through a class for this, you can simply export an object like below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';

const register = (name, username, mail, password) => {
  axios
    .post('/signup', {
      name: name,
      username: username,
      mail: mail,
      password: password,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return true;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      Alert.alert(error);
    });
};

export default { register };
```

And import like

```
import funciones from '../../funciones/funciones'
```

And use like

```
funciones.register(...);
```

Comment: You've said that the directory is correct right ?  can you check you tell the paths of both register.js and funciones.js ?

Comment: yes, the directory of "register" its ~/app/pages/register.js and "funciones" its ~/funciones/funciones.js

Comment: i dont see anything wrong with the paths, can you try moving function to same folder and try changing the path?

Comment: i try move the js file out directory and solved jaja ¿Maybe possible bug?

Comment: cant be a bug, all your files are inside the app folder right ? along with package json n all ?